# Is it safe to change ownership of several sub directories in /usr/local on MacOS Big Sur?

Tags: security, permissions, homebrew, chown, macos-bigsur

When trying to install some support for FORTRAN on my macBook running Big Sur and using brew I get an error that some /usr/local folders are not writeable and am asked to use *chown* to change ownership to me as a user.

Is this safe? (and will the change persist through an update?)

```
sudo chown -R $(whoami) /usr/local/bin /usr/local/include /usr/local/lib /usr/local/share /usr/local/share/info /usr/local/share/man /usr/local/share/man/man1 /usr/local/share/man/man7
```

and

```
chmod u+w /usr/local/bin /usr/local/include /usr/local/lib /usr/local/share /usr/local/share/info /usr/local/share/man /usr/local/share/man/man1 /usr/local/share/man/man7
```

Edit I couldn't create a new file in /usr/bin using sudo - 'not allowed', thanks Tetsujin.

When I try to build a 'Hello World' FORTRAN test it can't find gfortran which is in /usr/local/bin.

```
make all 
Building file: ../Hello.f90
Invoking: GNU Fortran Compiler
gfortran -funderscoring -O0 -g -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -o "Hello.o" "../Hello.f90"
/bin/sh: gfortran: command not found
make: *** [Hello.o] Error 127
"make all" terminated with exit code 2. Build might be incomplete.
```

Using terminal I can start gfortran from sh

```
nate@MacBook-Pro-2 ~ % sh
sh-3.2$ which gfortran
/usr/local/bin/gfortran
sh-3.2$ gfortran
gfortran: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
sh-3.2$
```

I netbeans wants me to install something in /usr/bin which macOS won't allow.  It's starting to sound like 'you can't get there from here.'

I guess I need to ask a new question.

Comment: I would very much doubt Big Sur would let you change ownership. The entire boot volume is protected. You need to re-work your structures to the user volume using synthetic symlinks.

Comment: @Tetsujin Thanks, see my edit.

Comment: @Tetsujin You could make your comment into an answer ...

Comment: No idea how to do what you asked. I’m just a guy with a lot of rep!